# How to create date with date and time and then compare it to another date

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my form I separated the date picker and time picker. Now I want to create a date with hours.

```html
<div class="form-group col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
  <div class="col-lg-6" style="padding-left: 0;">
      <label class="control-label " for="startDate">Start Date</label>
      <input type="text" class=" required form-control" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" id="datepicker-autoclose" name="startDate">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6" style="padding: 0;">
      <label class="control-label " for="startTime">Start Time</label>
      <div class="bootstrap-timepicker">
          <input id="timepicker3" name="startTime" type="text" class="required form-control">
      </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
  <div class="col-lg-6" style="padding-left: 0;">
      <label class="control-label " for="endDate">End Date</label>
      <input type="text" class=" required form-control" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" id="datepicker-autoclose2" name="endDate">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6" style="padding: 0;">
      <label class="control-label " for="endTime">End Time</label>
      <div class="bootstrap-timepicker">
          <input id="timepicker4" name="endTime" type="text" class="required form-control">
      </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
  <div class="col-lg-6" style="padding-left: 0;">
      <label class="control-label " for="deadlineDate">Registration Deadline Date</label>
      <input type="text" class=" required form-control" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" id="datepicker-autoclose5" name="deadlineDate">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6" style="padding: 0;">
      <label class="control-label " for="deadlineTime">Registration Deadline Time</label>
      <div class="bootstrap-timepicker">
          <input id="timepicker5" name="deadlineTime" type="text" class="required form-control">
      </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Just your own examples will help me. My end goal is to validate the dates which goes as
Start Date - should be greater than current time
End Date - should be greater than Start Date
Registration Deadline - should be greater than current time but less than start date

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript) after [What is the best way to parse a time into a Date object from user input in Javascript?](//stackoverflow.com/q/141348) and [How can I convert string to datetime with format specification in JavaScript?](//stackoverflow.com/q/476105)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC

```
datestr = '2018/03/06'
timestr = '13:10'
function toDate(dateStr, timeStr) { // assuming its a YYYY/MM/DD string
    var dateParts = dateStr.split("/");
    var timeParts = timeStr.split(":");
    date = new Date(dateParts[0], dateParts[1] - 1, dateParts[2]);
    date.setHours(timeParts[0]);
    date.setMinutes(timeParts[1]);
    return date;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create a `Date`, it produces a date/time object that can be examined as an integer (use **[`Date.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now)** to get this). You can then compare one integer against another (date against date). Whichever integer is greater is the one that is most current.

```js
var d1 = Date.now();
var d2 = null;
// Wait 2 seconds and make another date
setTimeout(function(){ 
  d2 = Date.now(); 

  // Look at what we have
  console.log("d1 is: " + d1.toLocaleString(), " - d2 is: " + d2.toLocaleString());
  console.log("The difference between the dates/times is: " + ((d2 - d1) / 1000) + " seconds.");
  
  // Compare:
  if(d1 > d2) {
    console.log("d1 is more current than d2");
  } else {
    console.log("d2 is more current than d1"); 
  }

}, 2000);
```

Comment: Why a down vote for a correct answer that shows how to do exactly what is being asked for?

Comment: was not the one who down voted. thanks for that example